# Adding a custom value to a collection

Tags: powerapps

Hello People Smarter than I am!

I have a power app I have created with drop boxes to filter a gallery.  The gallery is filtering properly in my drop box that is based on a collection.  My issue is that I cannot get 'ALL' items to show once I invoke the filter on the gallery.

The collection:

```
ClearCollect(
colJob,
Distinct(RBI_User_Actions_1,BusinessJobTitle)
);
```

The Drop box:

```
Sort(colJob,Value)
```

The visual:

[image]

I have been playing around with the following concept from a google search:

```
ClearCollect(
colJob,{Value:"ALL"}
);

ClearCollect(
colJob,
Distinct(RBI_User_Actions_1,BusinessJobTitle)
);
```

I have accomplished this in another drop box that has static values that will not change:

```
["","Incomplete", "1st Follow Up", "2nd Follow Up", "3rd Follow Up", "In Progress (Pending Transfer)","Complete (No Response)", "Complete"]
```

I unfortunately cannot do this for the previously mentioned drop boxes.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ClearCollect` on your second call, you should change it to `Collect` (which doesn't remove the previous elements):

```
ClearCollect(
  colJob,{Value:"ALL"}
);

Collect(
  colJob,
  Distinct(RBI_User_Actions_1,BusinessJobTitle)
);
```